# c# Static Member inside ForEach

Tags: c#, foreach, lambda, static

I have the following:

```
blocks.Where(x => x.BlockName == NAVIGATION)
      .ForEach(block => block.Data = db.Pages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList());
```

If `where` finds more than one block, how can I prevent the `db.Pages.Select` from performing the database hit for every block and simply reuse the `List` for the second and subsequent blocks.

Can you have static variables inside lambda functions?

UPDATE: I don't want to perform the fetch at all if the `where` finds zero blocks.

UPDATE: blocks is an in-memory List

Comment: Is `blocks` an entity being loaded from the database? In any case, why not just write `var names = db.Pages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();` at the start, store it in the variable, then use the variable inside the `ForEach`?

Comment: Sure, you can define the data list before (`var data = db.Pages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()`) and then use it inside the lambda: `... .ForEach(block => block.Data = data);`

Comment: The problem with fetching the data before is that if the `where` finds zero blocks, I don't want the fetch to take place at all.

Comment: Try this, then: `IEnumerable<string> data = null; foreach (var block in blocks.where(...) { block.Data = data ?? (data = db.pages.select(x => x.name)); }`

Comment: `var navigationBlocks = blocks.Where(x => x.BlockName == NAVIGATION).ToList(); if (navigationBlocks.Any()) { var data = db.Pages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList(); \\ and work with it }`

Comment: @Rob and Corak - Thanks for two good methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var blocksResult = blocks.Where(x => x.BlockName == NAVIGATION);
if (blocksResult.Any())
{
    var blockData = db.Pages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
    blocksResult.ForEach(block => block.Data = blockData);
}
```

OR

```
List<string> blockData = null;
blocks.Where(x => x.BlockName == NAVIGATION).ForEach(block => block.Data = (blockData ?? (blockData  = db.Pages.Select(x => x.Name).ToList())))
```

Comment: Thanks. In both of these, the `Where` returns an IEnumerable, not a List, and therefore does not have ForEach. But adding ToList sorts this.